# Efficient way to update JSON with key,value even it hit method 0.001 ms

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, for-loop

I need a best efficient way to loop through a json and compare with dict list and result a key-value pair if matches the key.

Here is code am trying. But, if my method get called every 0.001 ms then what will b the best way to process the data and send response.

```
import json


data = {"utc_start_at": "2018-09-29T16:45:00+0000","test":"gfds","ert":"erty"}
#data1 = json.loads(json_data) # json_data is a placeholder for your json
keys = ['results_count', 'test', 'utc_start_at', 'non_resource_bookable_capacity']

    
def find_key_value_pairs(q, keys, dicts=None):
    if not dicts:
        dicts = [q]
        q = [q]  

    data = q.pop(0)
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        data = data.values()

    for d in data:
        dtype = type(d)
        if dtype is dict or dtype is list:
            q.append(d)
            if dtype is dict:
                dicts.append(d)

    if q:
        return find_key_value_pairs(q, keys, dicts)

    return [(k, v) for d in dicts for k, v in d.items() if k in keys]
results = find_key_value_pairs(data, keys)
json_Obj={}
for k, v in results:
    json_Obj.update({k:v})

print(json_Obj)
```

Please guide me the best efficient way to iterate  and send json even it gets hit 0.001ms

Answer (score 0):

It is worth considering if the 'find_key_value_pairs' function is the actual  bottleneck in your application; in fact by calling the function every 0.001ms, it would be unlikely that optimizing the function will have significant impact on the overall performance.

Anyway, one way of optimizing would use be using a generator function to yield the key-value pairs rather than returning a list. This allows you to start processing the key-value tuples as soon as they are found rather than having to wait until the entire list has been generated.

```
def find_key_value_pairs(q, keys, dicts=None):
    if not dicts:
        dicts = [q]
        q = [q]  

    data = q.pop(0)
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        data = data.values()

    for d in data:
        dtype = type(d)
        if dtype is dict or dtype is list:
            q.append(d)
            if dtype is dict:
                dicts.append(d)

    if q:
        yield from find_key_value_pairs(q, keys, dicts)
    else:
        for d in dicts:
            for k, v in d.items():
                if k in keys:
                    yield k, v
```

You can then use the generator function as follows:

```
results = find_key_value_pairs(data, keys)
json_obj = {}
for k, v in results:
    json_obj[k] = v
```

Comment: Thanks @Asmar, Is there a still better way rather than method calling ? as you said calling method will be not a better approach.. so asking is there any better approach you suggest ?

Comment: If your business requirement is to call the method every 0.001ms then I cannot suggest any approach, other than the technical fine tuning of find_key_value_pairs method...

Comment: It depends... it was just assumption 0.001ms.. for this am thinking to use thread wait and acquire for incoming messages.  What do you suggest ?